# How can we use highlight feature with completion suggestion in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
"suggest": {
  "sourceText_suggestion": {
    "prefix": "12",
    "completion": {
      "field": "sourceText",
      "fuzzy": {
          "fuzziness": 2
       },
       "contexts": {
          "companyUid": ["1000467"]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

1. How can we use the highlight feature with completion?
2. Also, I found this not suitable for full-text search, how is it possible to search random words from any full text? Can we do it through completion or need to use any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to use Highlight with Completion Suggester, only in [Phrase Suggester.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#_basic_phrase_suggest_api_parameters)